# "Maintain our contact" or "stay in contact"

Tags: phrase-usage

Which of these phrases sound more natural to a native speaker in a professional/formal letter?

1. I would like to maintain our contact
2. I would like to stay in contact

I would like to express the desire to keep the recipients contact details in case of future opportunities for cooperation. To me, "stay in contact" sounds like I am pursuing an ongoing, active exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Books Ngram viewer shows that of the four phrases most likely to be used in this context, by far the most popular is **stay in touch**.

Next comes **maintain contact**, followed far behind by **stay in contact**, with **maintain our contact** in last place.

Although **stay in touch** has achieved its popularity only over the last 60 years, it has soared into top position. It's slightly more informal than **maintain contact** but would not sound out of place in a formal letter.

So I would go with either of the first two options although there is nothing wrong either idiomatically or grammatically with the last two.

It's really just a matter of preference.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stay+in+contact%2Cmaintain+contact%2Cmaintain+our+contact%2Cstay+in+touch&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstay%20in%20contact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaintain%20contact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaintain%20our%20contact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstay%20in%20touch%3B%2Cc0